# Checking if you're in home directory (linux)

Tags: c, linux, path, directory

I'm writing a program that ascends a file system hierarchy from a given path, so if the path given is `/home/users/foo/bar`, it will go back 1 directory until it hits the first, in this case `/home`

What's the best way to detect this? My only solution is to check how many backspaces there are, but is there a better way? I'm afraid this might not work on different distros.

My code to open the parent directory is:

```
snprintf(ptr2, path_max_size, "%s/..", argv[1]);
d = opendir(ptr2);
```

I just need to add a `while (dir != home)` statement

Comment: `echo ~` on the shell shows you the home directory. Now you should be able to compare the current dir with the home dir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [getenv()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) like this:

```
snprintf(homedir, MAX_PATH, "%s", getenv("HOME"));
```

and then check if `homedir` is what you have descended to.

---

If you are looking for something that works both on Windows and Linux check [this](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/164689-how-get-users-home-directory.html).